PDF printing: "Processing - cfFilterChain: ghostscript (PID XXXX) exited with no errors."
I just to put out this question to see if anybody else is having this problem, and if anyone has tips or pointers on how to debug; I've found one other Manjaro Linux forum post about it, but no solution.
I have Ubuntu 23.10; Thinkpad X1 Carbon 3rd; Canon Pixma870; CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.4.
This system was printing just fine last week, but this week any attempt to print a pdf from the default document viewer ends with (in the printer status) the error message in the title. I have rebooted computer and printer multiple times. Printing text from LibreOffice writer works fine.

This seems to have been caused by setting the "image quality" to "300X300 DRAFT" instead of "300x300".
Not the best error handling, not sure what's wrong with "300x300 DRAFT", but at least I can print now.

Not sure what exactly causes this, but a reboot of the printer + PC seems to fix it for me.
Side note - I don't have the same quality option OP seems to have access to, or at least I don't know where to find that.
